# Run command without adding it to the history

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a clean history of commands for a specific task. As a result, I would like to specific which commands to keep in history and which commands not to keep. For instance, to prevent a command from going into the history, I would like to be able to run something like this:

```
cls -no-history
```

That would prevent cluttering the history with `cls` commands. For the time being, I am just running `clear-history -id 7`, for instance, to delete specific history items.

Comment: But running `Clear-History` will also appear in the history, so what's the reward of doing this? replacing one unwanted entry with another? :)

Comment: @FrodeF. I know. It sucks. The reward happens when removing many commands. Then I can replace seven with one.

Comment: That makes sense! Publish-Script makes use of the `-NuGetApiKey` which ideally I don't want to save to history...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really interesting question. I think I've come up with a way that will actually do this for you, but you need to define a function and then pipe the command you want out of the history into that function.

```powershell
function Skip-History {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(
        ValueFromPipeline=$true
    )]
    [Object]
    $o
)
    Begin {
        $history = Get-History
    }

    Process {
        $o
    }

    End {
        Clear-History
        $history | Add-History
    }
}
```

To use it:

```powershell
cls | Skip-History
Get-Process | Skip-History
```

A downside of this is that it will constantly be re-numbering your history IDs, if that matters.

Also, through further experimentation, it seems that this will not work unless you use it directly after each cmdlet in a pipeline. So if you wanted to hide `Get-Process | Sort-Object` you would have to call it like this:

```powershell
Get-Process | Skip-History | Sort-Object | Skip-History
```

Comment: The downside of renumbering the history ID doesn't matter.

Comment: Made a quick edit (the `Process` block should pass the object along, otherwise it's not useful with cmdlets like `Get-Process` or `Get-ChildItem` that actually use the pipeline objects).

Answer (score 6):

Caution, as of Windows 10 you'll need to also remove any new entries from %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadline\ConsoleHost_history.txt otherwise it will still appear in the "up arrow" list of previous commands.

You can do this with a text editor.